# get latitudes and longitudes within given radius and from a given latitude and longitude in meters

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get all the possible latitudes and longitudes withing some meter range from a given latitude and longitude. The following is the MySQL query I found. But the following one is checking distance in KM. I want in meters. Can somebody help how to modify the query so that I get directly within certain meters and not KM?

```
SELECT id, location_name,
(6371 * acos( cos( radians(@myLat) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians(@myLng)) + sin(radians(@myLat)) * sin(radians(latitude)) )) as distance FROM sample.locations 
HAVING distance <= 50
```

Here 50 is KM and not meters. How to give in meters? I cannot always convert meters to KM in this query as my data is in meters. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6371 is the radius of the earth in km.  Change that to meters.
From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius)

> For Earth, the mean radius is 6,371.0088 km (3,958.7613 mi).[[16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#cite_note-Moritz2000-24)]

6,371.0088 km = 6,371,008.8 m

```
SELECT id, location_name,
(6371008.8 * acos( cos( radians(@myLat) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians(@myLng)) + sin(radians(@myLat)) * sin(radians(latitude)) )) as distance FROM sample.locations 
HAVING distance <= 50
```